# Gradle multi-modules: If gradle.build file is changed for each sub module. No tasks are available

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am working with `Gradle` 3.5 and I have the following situation.

I work with `Spring Framework` through *multi modules*. 
Consider the following structure:

```
root
   build.gradle
child-01
   build.gradle
child-02
   build.gradle
child-03
   build.gradle
```

Until here all is Ok.

From above observe each `.gradle` file has the same name. It is `build`

Through the `gradle tasks` command is possible list in the console all my own tasks for each `build.gradle` file from each sub module. Furthermore, if the `gradle project` command is used I can see each project listed with its respective *description*.

Working with `Jenkins` all work fine where I am able to call any task from any `build.gradle` file from each sub module

I did the following variation:

```
root
   build.gradle
child-01
   child-01.gradle
child-02
   child-02.gradle
child-03
   child-03.gradle
```

For each submodule each `build.gradle` file has been renamed to `child-0#.gradle` respectively

Now the `gradle tasks` command does not print my own tasks and `Jenkins` fails because the tasks are not available. The `gradle project` command prints all the sub modules but without the description.

What is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as each subproject's build file name matches the subproject name, you can update your `settings.gradle` file with:

```
rootProject.children.each {
    it.buildFileName = "${it.name}.gradle"
}
```

That way you do not need to call out each project buildFileName explicity.

Here is a discussion on the topic:

https://discuss.gradle.org/t/child-projects-with-different-names-other-than-build-gradle/4636

Answer (score 1):

You can change build file name by set a value for appropriate property **buildFileName** in **settings.gradle** file.

```
project(':child-01').buildFileName = 'child-01.gradle'
```

For more details check this link [Modifying elements of the project tree](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sub:modifying_element_of_the_project_tree)